# How to write a program that checks that the value of sin^2(θ) + cos^2(θ)?

Tags: java

I am doing my Java programming homework and need help with explanation on the following question:
Write a program that uses `Math.sin()` and `Math.cos()` to check that the value of 
sin<sup>2</sup>θ + cos<sup>2</sup>θ is approximately 1 for any θ entered as a command-line argument. Just print the value. Why are the values not always exactly 1?

Comment: Why don't you **try it and see**?

Comment: The values aren't exactly 1 because numbers, on a computer, aren't usually stored exactly but in a finite storage space. Look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point and http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: show the code you tried so far

Comment: *Why are the values not always exactly1?* - floating point arithmetic is not precise.  A precise representation of an irrational number requires an infinite amout of space :-)

Comment: It's because of **IEEE 754**. You will always see such issue in `float` and `double` values. There are lots of questions on SO about this.

Comment: Great, answering other people's homework :-(

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9425994/1224741

Answer (score 4):

#### Rule #1:

Don't compare floating point numbers with equality (==). The best way to check for equality in floating numbers, is to define some threshold nears to ZERO and compare the difference between the two numbers against that threshold

In your case, your target number is **1**, and the result could be for example **0.999998**

```
double threshold = 0.00001; // 1e-5
double target = 1;
double result = 0.999998; 

System.out.println(Math.abs(target - result) < threshold); // prints true
```

Comment: Not near zero necessarily, it depends on the value range and is more complicated.